# N+1 problem when fetching OneToOne select

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a table A which has one to one mapping of table B.
B has one To many mapping of table C.

When I write  `select a from A a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.B`

Query runs N+1 time to fill values of C in B.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`select a from A a JOIN FETCH a.B b JOIN FETCH b.c c`

Comment: you should provide your entities